# How to update google doc using google docs api (Python)

Tags: python, json, google-docs-api

I'm new to Google Docs api and want to be able to add text using the replaceText option. How would I set this up? I am doing this in Python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the steps from Google Docs API [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) using Python. Then try to run this code to insert text using [`InsertTextRequest`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#InsertTextRequest) method:

```
requests = [
     {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 25,
            },
            'text': text1
        }
    },
             {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 50,
            },
            'text': text2
        }
    },
             {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 75,
            },
            'text': text3
        }
    },
]

result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

To insert text into a document, use the `BatchUpdate` method and include an `InsertTextRequest` with the text and location as the payload. It's better to use this suggested method in the documentation.

Comment: Any ideas about how to insert a header and a footer?

Comment: Had a followup question to @jess how do we identify the index? Can we use key, value? to make sure if give the heading as key?